# Sunrise and sunset photography with a small digital camera

Tags: camera-settings, panasonic, sunrise, sunset

I have a new camera (Panasonic TZ 30) and I am a relatively inexperienced photographer. I will shortly be doing a journey as tourist at the famous monolith, [Uluru](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uluru) in Central Australia.

I was thinking that I should try to set up one or more custom settings beforehand so I will be ready to take my chances when the moment comes to capture the scene at sunrise and sunset.

I would welcome suggestions on how should I set up my camera.

Answer (score 6):

Most P&S I have used does amazing jobs with the built-in presets (Scene modes)! Though most people think the presets are targeted towards amateurs, but trust me they are not! The companies have invested heavy amount of research and money to configure these presets often using real life feedback from very experienced photographers. So I'd not underestimate them. In fact, for relatively inexperienced photographers, chances of getting better images are higher using these presets, rather than using custom configurations.

After taking a look at the [specifications and available presets](http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/panasonic-lumix-dmc-zs20-tz30-review/2) of your camera, I'd suggest you to try these presets: Scenery, Night Scenery, Sunset. Also presets like HDR, Hand Held Night Shot, High Sensitivity are likely to produce good results. You'll have to try it yourself.

Comment: +1 - I pretty much agree except the comment about the target audience of scene modes... They're definitely aimed at amateurs, but that doesn't mean that they can't be useful to pros or semi-pros as well. There is, after all, a reason you do not find these modes on the high end camera bodies.